# Average compared with discrete average for some $\lbrace -1,1 \rbrace$ polynomials

Tags: polynomials, cv.complex-variables

Let $k>0$ be a positive integer. Set $n=4k.$ Let $R(t)$ be a polynomial of degree $n-1$
with coefficients in $\lbrace -1,1 \rbrace$.

Consider the discrete average

$$
D(n,R) = \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \vert R(exp(2\pi i j/n)) \vert}{n}
$$

and the average

$$
A(n,R) = \frac{\int_{0}^{2\pi} \vert R(exp(it) \vert dt}{2\pi}.
$$

When $k=1$ so that $n=4$ we have that for one half of the possible polynomials $R(t)$
$$
D(n,R) \leq A(n,R).
$$

Question: What happens when $k>1.$

Comment: I don't know. Your $A(n,R)$ (which doesn't actually depend on $n$) is essentially the Mahler measure of $R$, q.v.

Comment: Thanks to Gerry and to Or.  

In order to have a feeling of what happens when $n$ is `big`  
(so that computations may become more complicated).
Can be useful to observe (besides nice gerry's observation) that
$$
A(n,R) = \int_{0}^{1} \vert R(exp(2\pi i t) \vert dt
$$
so that seems that some kind of `Riemann sums` are involved ?



Comment: You can interpret $D(n,R)$ as a Riemann sum for $A(R)$. There are estimates for the difference between the two in terms of properties of $R$ and of the set $\lbrace0,1/n,\dots,(n-1)/n\rbrace$ - see Koksma's inequality, also the Erdos-Turan inequality. Those inequalities won't tell you anything about the sign of the difference. For that, you'd have to walk through the proofs of the inequalities. One reference is the Kuipers-Niederreiter book on Uniform Distribution of Sequences. 

Comment: Warn to myself: Since the polynomial $R(t)$ has degree $n-1$ (that depends on $n$)
seems that we cannot
let $n$ go to infinity to recover the `integral` from the `Riemann Sum`.
 


Comment: I just discover that these polynomials $R(t)$ are called `Littlewood polynomials`
See the nice paper of  Peter Borwein and Michael Mossinghoff (available on the net):
The $L_1$ norm of polynomials.



Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claims seems to be false. Numerical integration for $k=2, (n=8)$ gives that 
for $152$ out of the $256=2^8$ polynomials ($59.3\%$) you have $D(n,R) \leq A(n,R)$.

I do not see why having n a multiple of 4 should matter. 
The fact that for half of polynomials the inequality holds at $n=4$ seems like a coincident. You get the following numbers for different values of $n$: 
($m$ is the number of polynomials for which $D \leq A$)

### $n$,   $2^n$,   $m$,    $fraction$

```
1    2    2    1.000
2    4    4    1.000
3    8    6    0.750
4   16    8    0.500
5   32   16    0.500
6   64   36    0.562
7  128   66    0.515
8  256  152    0.593
```

Comment: @Or: Thanks again for calculations. I  would know if the inequalities that hold
depends or not on the corresponding circulant matrix being singular or not.  More precisely
we can attach to each such polynomial $R(t)= r_0 + \ldots + r_{n-1}t^{n-1}$ a circulant matrix 
$C(R)$ that has 
first row precisely $r_0, \ldots, r_{n-1}.$  Take the inequality $A(n,R) \leq D(n,R)$ for example.
Is this inequality satisfied by about the same number of $R$'s with $det(C(R))=0$ as well
as about the same number of $R$'s with $\det(C(R)) \neq 0$ ???


Comment: That's interesting. Why is the relation to the circulant matrix? For $n=4$ indeed $A \geq D$ iff $det(C)=0$. In general this doesn't hold but statistically it might be more likely 
to get $A \geq D$ when $det(C)=0$. For example, for $n=8$ you have

$56 (A\geq D,det\neq 0)$, $96 (A\geq D,det=0)$, $72 (A < D,det \neq 0)$, $32 (A < D,det=0)$,
 
